# Comparing Elements within a Multi-Dimensional Array

Tags: excel, vba

Assume I have an array of the dimensions `comb(x, y)`.
For each element x I need to check if any of the elements y are identical. If so, I will proceed with the next element of x.

If there were 4 elements stored in y for each x the code I would use would be something like this:

```
For i = 0 To z
    j = 0
    k = j + 1
    l = j + 2
    m = j + 3

    If comb(i, j) <> comb(i, k) And _
    comb(i, j) <> comb(i, l) And _
    comb(i, j) <> comb(i, m) And _
    comb(i, k) <> comb(i, l) And _
    comb(i, k) <> comb(i, m) And _
    comb(i, l) <> comb(i, m) Then

       MsgBox "success"

    End If

 Next i
```

The thing is, that the dimension of y changes depending on the user input.
Is there a way to automate it for an arbitrary number of elements in y?

Comment: Does ubound(comb(2)) not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With K.Davis' great help I found the following solution to my problem:

```
For x = LBound(comb, 1) To UBound(comb, 1)
   For y = LBound(comb, 2) To UBound(comb, 2) - 1
      For z = y + 1 To UBound(comb, 2)
         If comb(x, y) = comb(x, z) Then
            noMatch = True
         End If
      Next z
   Next y

   If noMatch = False Then
      MsgBox x
   End If

   noMatch = False

Next x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create three loops that will check each value, but will skip over each other due to the final loop being `y + 1` from the second loop.

```
Dim x As Long, y As Long, z As Long, comb()

For x = LBound(comb, 1) To UBound(comb, 1)
    For y = LBound(comb, 2) To UBound(comb, 2) - 1
        For z = y + 1 To UBound(comb, 2)
            If comb(x, y) = comb(x, z) Then
                msgbox "Match Occurred!"
            End If
        Next z
    Next y
Next x
```

Essentially, the 2nd loop controls the left side of the equation (the `If comb(x, y) =` and the 3rd loop controls the right side (the `= comb(x, z)`).

---

If desired, to prevent errors where there only may be a single value in the 2nd dimension, you could add an extra **If..Then** statement, like:

```
If Lbound(comb, 2) <> Ubound(comb, 2) Then ...
```

due to the nature of how the third loop adds 1 to `y`'s value, but an error would be raised if there isn't a 1 to add to `y`.

---

## Visualization

Here is a good visualization to see how this works. This test will print each iteration to the immediate window, you can see that each number is compared with a different number:

```
Sub test()

    Dim x As Long, y As Long, z As Long, comb(0, 0 To 4)

    For x = LBound(comb, 1) To UBound(comb, 1)
        For y = LBound(comb, 2) To UBound(comb, 2) - 1
            For z = y + 1 To UBound(comb, 2)
                If comb(x, y) = comb(x, z) Then
                    Debug.Print y & "|" & z
                End If
            Next z
        Next y
    Next x

End Sub
```

Which the immediate window prints:

> ```
> 0|1  
> 0|2  
> 0|3  
> 0|4  
> 1|2  
> 1|3  
> 1|4  
> 2|3  
> 2|4  
> 3|4
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! This is headed in the right direction, but lacks a key element. 
Think of the elements in the 2nd dimension as a set. I want to filter for those sets where there occurs not a single element twice.

Assume again the dimension is 4 and I have these elements: comb(0,0)="a" ;comb(0,1)="b"; comb(0,2)="a"; comb(0,3)="b"

with your method I would get 2 matches because element 0=2 and element 1=3